# Recursively register types in Unity container

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm working on a existing asp.net project. In that project I'm using unity container version 5.2.0.0 for dependency injection. Since it is big project there are plenty of types to register o the unity container and again those types have more dependencies. Its grown recursively. Is there any way to manage this hierarchically growing of my unity container or should I register all these dependencies.

```
//For Type1
container.RegisterType<ITypeA, TypeA>();
container.RegisterType<ITypeB, TypeB>();
container.RegisterType<ITypeC, TypeC>();

//For Type2
container.RegisterType<ITypeD, TypeD>();

//For TypeA
container.RegisterType<ITypeP, TypeP>();
container.RegisterType<ITypQ, TypeQ>();

//For TypeP
container.RegisterType<ITypeS, TypeS>();
container.RegisterType<ITypR, TypeR>();
```

Now my container like this. Actually worst than this. So how can I get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can Register all dependencies with using unity config.

First add unity to config sections in `App.config` and give source (`MyUnityDependencies.config` etc.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <unity configSource="MyUnityDependencies.config" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

In `MyUnityDependencies.config` you can add register types for each Container:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<unity>
  <container name="MyContainer">
    <register name="Dependency1"
              type="ITypeA"
              mapTo="TypeA" >
    </register>
    <register name="Dependency2"
              type="ITypeB"
              mapTo="TypeB" >
    </register>
    ...
  </container>

</unity>
```

Finally you can Register all dependencies with  [`LoadConfiguation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff661700(v%3Dpandp.30))

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration("MyContainer");
```

Comment: Are you sure this is better? An engineer will still have to type all that stuff. Without the benefit of compile time checking or IntelliSense.

Comment: I mean it could be usefull. Yes engineer still have to type all that stuff, not in code but in config. Also it allows us to draw dependency map at runtime via this config. Moreover it provides extentibility too, for example you can generate this config automatically by using XSD etc.